# Delete file from SFTP server using sftp protocol in shell script

Tags: shell, sftp, file-transfer

I'm new to shell scripting. I'm trying to delete a file from a remote server using `SFTP` protocol. Though I'm able to download the file, but I'm unable to delete post download. This is my code:

```
sftp -oPort=22 $FTP_USER@$FTP_SVR:$TEST_PATH/TEST_*.dat.gpg $LAND
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      Error "Cannot Download TEST file from SFTP Server"
   fi

sftp -oPort=22 $FTP_USER@$FTP_SVR:$TEST_PATH/n rm TEST_*.dat.gpg
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Removing TEST Files from SFTP Server"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sftp` as you’re using it is similar to `ssh` command in that it logs you into the remote server, so try and develop your command without any “if” logic, and add it later if necessary. Here’s a version of what you already have without then if logic:

```
sftp -oPort=22 $FTP_USER@$FTP_SVR; get $TESTPATH/TEST_.dat.gpg $LAND; rm TEST_.dat.gpg; bye
```

Note that if you can’t get the file, you also shouldn’t be able to delete it, which makes the “if” logic between the two sftp commands not really critical.